# How To divide parallel and sequential tests using TestNG with Cucumber

Tags: java, cucumber, testng

I have a framework that uses `TestNG` with `Cucumber` and runs in parallel. 
Now i need some of my tests to be run sequentially.
There are some cases to do such trick with `exclude` option in TestNG xml. But, since im using `Cucumber`, i have only one `@Test` method, that parses cucumber features and runs its step definitions so i can't modify any particular `@Test`.

I think i can do what i need by creating only one step definition for sequential step, then `synchronized` it with some `static` lock. But in my opinion this is way too ugly and unconvenient to use and read. But i hope there is some more clear and easy to achieve way.

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: Could you find a solution?

Comment: no, there is no nice looking way to achive that unfortunately. You can try something using listeners and custom annotations